# Protecting global variable when using multiple threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

The C program I am writing in linux creates multiple threads (in this case 8) and each thread should run the function compute() which will increase a global variable "total" by a 1000. The program currently works as expected in this regard as it outputs the final total as 8000.

At the moment the order in which the threads execute the compute function and alter the "total" variable does not matter but I want to ensure that each thread does not alter the global variable until it is not being used by any other thread.

If anyone could point me in the right direction on how i should implement POSIX semaphores to achieve this that would be greatly appreciated as this area/threads in general is new to me.

The current code for the program is below.
Many thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define N 8 /* define the total number of processes we want */
/* Set global variable */
float total=0;

/* compute function just does something. */
int compute()
{
  int i;
  float oldTotal =0, result =0;

  /*for a large number of times just square root and square the arbitrary number 1000*/
  for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)  //Arbitrary number to allow process to run for a while.
      {
        result = sqrt(1000.0)*sqrt(1000.0);
      }

  /*Print the result - should be no suprise*/
  printf("Result is %f\n", result); 

  /*We want to keep a running total in the global variable total*/
  oldTotal = total;   
  total = oldTotal + result;

  /*Print the running total so far*/
  printf("Total is %f\n", total);
  return(0);
}


void* thread_procedure(void* param)
{

    int i = (int)param;
    /* give a message about the proc ID */
    printf("Process Id for process %d is %d\n",i,getpid());
    /* call the function to do some computation. If we used sleep
    The process would simply sleep. We do not want that */

    compute(); 

    return NULL;
}


int main()
{
  int i, j;
  sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1); //Initialise mutex 
  pthread_t thread[N];   //Array of threads, N number of processes     


  printf("\n"); /* bit of whitespace */
  /* We want to loop to create the required number of processes
  Note carefully how only the child process is left to run */
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      /* start new thread and catch it if it/one fails */
      j = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &thread_procedure, (void*)i);
      if (j)
          {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
          }
    }


  /* joining with threads */
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
       {
          pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
       }

  sem_destroy(&mutex); 
  /* nothing else to do so end main function (and program) */
  return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: [**Mut**ual **Ex**clusion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html)

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may suggest the use of pthread [mutex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) that also achieves mutual exclusion to shared variables, the example below accomplishes. It might be quicker in what you are trying to accomplish.

```
#include <pthread.h>

//Shared global variable
float total = 0;

//Shared lock
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 

//some thread function that adds 1,000 to total one thread at a time
void *compute(){

    //If no thread is using the lock, acquire lock and add 1,000 to total. The lock prevents other threads from executing this piece of code during a context switch. 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    total += 1000;
    //Release lock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;

}
```

This way, if thread `T1` executes the compute function and the lock is free, it will acquire the lock, increment total, and then release the lock. If thread `T2` calls compute while `T1` has the lock, `T2` will not be able to continue beyond that point in the code and will wait until the lock resource is freed by `T1`. Thus it protects the global variable; threads that wish to mutate shared variables are unable to do so at the same time while one thread holds the lock.

Comment: Thanks, i went with this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use mutex's or semaphore's